# Setting background for basic android app

Tags: android, background, background-image

I am currently working on a basic app using eclipse as my IDE. I am currently having trouble setting an image as my background. I was following a tutoral which told me to place my image in the drawable-mdpi folder and name it as icon. I have tried this but it keeps on placing in the andriod icon instead even when i delete the andriod icon image. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/background"></LinearLayout>
```

background is a .png file. with borders draw around it with Nine9Patch.

Hope this helps